# Django RSS feed according to category

Tags: python, django, rss

I have a model Question -

```
class Question(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=1024)
    content = models.TextField()
    answer = models.TextField()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=512)
    flags = models.IntegerField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

I have several cateogries according to which I want the RSS to be displayed. I saw the documentation and came up with this -

```
class CategoryFeed(Feed):

    def get_object(self, request, category):
        return Question.objects.filter(category__exact=1)[:1][0]

    def title(self, obj):
        return "The Quiz Machine: latest questions for category %s" % obj.category

    def link(self, obj):
        return '/rss/{0}'.format(obj.category)

    def description(self, obj):
        return "Question for category %s" % obj.category

    def items(self, obj):
        return Question.objects.filter(category__exact=obj.category).order_by('-pub_date')[:30]

    def item_title(self, item):
        return item.title

    def item_link(self, item):
        return '/{0}/'.format(item.id)
```

But it gives me error when I'm accessing 'rss/physics'  saying that 'list index out of range. 
There is a physics question in the table. It is displayed on the index page already.  I'm not understanding the documentation.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your method:

```
def get_object(self, request, category):
    return Question.objects.filter(category__exact=1)[:1][0]
```

You have `category__exact=1`

which needs to be `category__exact=category`

That is:

```
def get_object(self, request, category):
    return Question.objects.filter(category__exact=category)[:1][0]
```

To make it more foolproof, I would do:

```
def get_object(self, request, category):
    qs = Question.objects.filter(category__exact=category)[:1]
    if qs:
        return qs[0]
    return None
```

Comment: Oh, silly me! Thanks man! I'll mark it correct in about 5 mins.